# Must I free a BSTR (WideString) allocated with SysAllocString?

Tags: delphi, memory-management, delphi-7

I have this code (I need to add string object to TStringList):

```
var
  WS: WideString;
begin
  WS := 'allocated string';
  SL.AddObject('my string', TObject(SysAllocString(PWideChar(WS))));
```

And later read it:

```
var
  WS: WideString;
begin
  WS := PWideChar(SL.Objects[0]);
  ShowMessage(WS);
```

I was wondering if the system will take care of the BSTR which was allocated with [`SysAllocString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221458(v=vs.85).aspx). or must I call `SysFreeString`? it's not clear from the documentation.

Now, If the system does De-allocates it, is there any way to prove it does?

**P.S:**
Infact, it is suffucient to call:

```
SL.AddObject('my string', TObject(PWideChar(WS)));
```

Without using `SysAllocString`. (and I can't understand how it works)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here the following line does allocate a new `BSTR` and fill its pointer to the `SL.Objects[]` pointer.

```
  SL.AddObject('my string', TObject(SysAllocString(PWideChar(WS))));
```

So the following *will* definitively leak memory:

```
var
  WS: WideString;
begin
  WS := PWideChar(SL.Objects[0]);
```

Here a *new* WS instance will be allocated, so your BSTR instance pointed by `SL.Objects[0]` won't be released.

And the following is working by chance:

```
SL.AddObject('my string', TObject(PWideChar(WS)));
```

The memory pointed by the `PWideChar(WS)` memory buffer is still containing to the previous `WS: WideString` instance. So is may work... until the buffer is re-used and overriden by some other data, and another text is returned, or a random GPF occurs.

By advice: never cheat the Delphi type system, storing something else than a `TObject` in a variable typed as `TObject`... unless you know what you are doing. Don't play with pointers until you know what they are and how they work.

I do not see any benefit of storing a `WideString` within a `TStrings.Object[]` entry! Change your data structure: create a true `class`, storing your string. Then everything would be clear and clean:

```
type
  TMyStoreWS = class
  protected
    fText: WideString;
  public
    constructor Create(const aText: WideString); virtual;
    property Text: WideString read fText write fText;
  end;

constructor TMyStoreWS.Create(const aText: WideString);
begin
  inherited Create;
  fText := aText;
end;

...
SL.AddObject('my string', TMyStoreWS.Create(aText)); // clean
...
ShowMessage(SL.Objects[0].Text); // clean
SL.Objects[0].Free; // don't forget to release
```

The small overhead of allocating a `class` instance is negligeable in regard to a `BSTR` string allocation, I can tell you. And your code would definitively be cleaner and easier to maintain/evolve.

Comment: I was hoping to let the system manage the destruction of the WideString "object". if I use a class structure I need to manually free each object (there is no OwnsObject in D7 for TStringList). I'm still not sure if I **must** free strings which are allocated with `SysAllocString` or the system can take care of that for me?...

Comment: Yes, you **must** free BSTR strings allocated by SysAllocString.

Answer (score 4):

Delphi will free the WideString as soon as it goes out of scope.
Because WideString is a managed type.
However if you cast the widestring to a PWideChar, Delphi does not count that as a reference and will thus destroy the string as soon as the function exits, even though there is still a reference to it.

That's bad because now you've got a dangling pointer. This is why you need `SysAllocString`.

What `SysAllocString` does is make a copy of the string you feed in. This copy is not managed, so you'll need to destroy it yourself using `SysFreeString`.